# How to avoid the '&' operator in strings

Tags: php, html

I have the following piece of code.

```
<?php
    $agentId = "LTH001";
    echo "&&" . $agentId;
?>
```

The output is `&<H001` whereas I expected `&&LTH001`. I guess there is a conversion issue causing this output. Why do I get the unexpected output?

Comment: hey its still not giving a desired output. Does it have to do anything with the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars in order to avoid HTML converting of undesired strings:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("&&".$agentId);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your output is: `&&LTH001`.

Your browser is seeing the `&LT` and interpreting it as a character code (albeit a malformed one), and replacing it with `<`.

Please View Source or use `htmlspecialchars` next time ;)